# Datatype mismatch

Tags: java, interface, type-conversion

I declared the following variable with the `Optional<string>` datatype which I had to do because of an Interface implementation

```
public Optional<String> value;
```

Now I need to write the below line of code which gives datatype mismatch error

```
value = input.readString();
```

Is there any way where I can type cast `input.readString();` to datatype `Optional<string>`

Comment: What is this `Optional` datatype? Please post it's definition.

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html Is this it?

Comment: I am assuming it's Guava's `Optional<T>` type.

Comment: If you are talking about Optional in google Guava, then you need to use  value = Optional.of(input.readString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it as follows:

`value = Optional.of(input.readString());`

You do not *cast* to or from Optional. It is an entirely different type which has a **generic type parameter.**